# How to upload and open a file in xampp apache server using CGI Perl Script?

Tags: apache, perl, cgi

This code works fine in my local xampp apache server. I run the same code in local area network with different ip addressed system. The file cannot open and i cant write it to the expected directory. Kindly do the needful? Thanks in advance.

Am passing the xml file through below code.

```
#!"C:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe"
#!"172.18.5.23:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe"
#!\usr\bin\perl -wT
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
my $query = new CGI;
print $query->header( "text/html" );
print <<END_HERE;


 <html>
      <head>
        <title>My First CGI Script</title>
      </head>
      <body bgcolor="#FFFFCC">
        <h1>Welcome to Perl CGI</h1>
        <form action="/cgi-bin/inputxml.cgi" method="post"
        enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p>Files to Upload: <input type="file" name="xml" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit Form" /></p>
        </form>
      </body>
    </html>
    END_HERE
```

sending the xml file to the below code.....

```
#!"C:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe"
    #!"172.18.5.23:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe"
    #!\usr\bin\perl -wT
    #!perl
    use strict;
    use CGI;
    use Cwd 'abs_path';
    use CGI::Carp qw(warningsToBrowser fatalsToBrowser);
    use File::Basename;
    $CGI::POST_MAX;
    my $safe_filename_characters = "a-zA-Z0-9_.-";
    my $query = new CGI;
        my $cgi = new CGI;
        my $file = $cgi->param('xml');
        my $lines;
        open(DATA,"<$file") or die "Can't open data";
        print $query->header ( );
        $lines = <DATA>;
        close(DATA);
        $lines =~s{darling}{CGI}ig;
        print $lines;
        print abs_path($file);
        open(OUT, '>dirname($file)."\\out_".basename($file)');
        print OUT $lines;
        close(OUT);


        print $query->header ( );
    print <<END_HERE;
```

Comment: You need to start checking for errors, for exmaple `open(DATA,"<$file") or die "Can't open data";` becomes `open(DATA,"<$file") or die "Can't open data: $!";`. See also [perldoc open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html)

Comment: that is also i have done but the same error shown cannot open the data from file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Getting the filename from the input parameter ("xml" in this case) is always a really bad idea. Browsers differ in their behaviour. Some give you the full filename, some only give you the basename. When they give you the full path, it will be the path on the **client** computer - a path that is pretty much guaranteed not to exist on your server. [**Update:** And re-reading your question, I realise that's exactly why it works when you're testing it locally.]

There's a detailed [explanation of how to do this](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#Processing-a-file-upload-field) in the documentation for the [CGI module](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI). You should really read all of that section before writing your code. But in summary.

```
# Get the filename which may well include a path and which
# should never be used as a filename on the server.
my $filename = $cgi->param('xml');

# Try to calculate a local filename
my $local_fn;
if ($filename =~ /([-\w\.]+)$/) {
  $local_fn = $1;
}

# Get file handle to uploaded file
my $local_in_fh = $cgi->upload('xml');

# Open a file handle to store the file
open $local_out_fh, '>', "/path/to/output/dir/$local_fn" or die $!;

while (<$local_in_fh>) {
  # process one line from the input file (which is in $_)
  print $local_out_fh;
}
```

There are a couple of other things that might be useful for you.

`$cgi->uploadInfo($filename)->{'Content-Type'}` will give you the MIME type of the uploaded file. You can use that to work out how you want to process the file.

`$cgi->tmpFileName($filename)` will give you the path to the temp file where your data has been uploaded. This will be deleted when the CGI program exits. But if you just want to save the file without processing it in any way, you can just move this file to a new location on your server.

Some other notes about your existing solution:

1. Your first program just displays a HTML file. So why not have a static HTML file?
2. `$CGI::POST_MAX` does nothing.
3. Please use `CGI->new` instead of `new CGI`.
4. You create two CGI objects (`$query` and `$cgi`). You only need one.
5. You print the CGI header twice.
6. DATA is a special file handle name. You shouldn't use it for your own file handles.
7. `$lines = <DATA>` will only get the first line from the file.
8. `open(OUT, '>dirname($file)."\\out_".basename($file)')` isn't doing anything like what you think it's doing.