# Read and Write the file in cgi perl script using xampp apache server?

Tags: apache, perl, xampp, cgi

Am going read and write the xml file.
i upload the xml file using below html code.
if i put the xml file in cgi-bin folder it will execute and display

```
 #!"C:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe"
     use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;

my $cgi = new CGI;
print $cgi->header( "text/html" );

print <<END_HERE;
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My First CGI Script</title>
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="#FFFFCC">
    <p>Welcome to Perl CGI</p>

    <form action="/cgi-bin/inputxml.cgi" method="post"
    enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>Files to Upload: <input type="file" name="xml" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit Form" /></p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
END_HERE
```

But if i put the xml file in any other folder or drive (except cgi-bin folder) it shows Can't open data at C:/xampp/cgi-bin/inputxml.cgi

```
#!"C:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe"
            use strict;
            use CGI;
            use Cwd 'abs_path';
            use CGI::Carp qw(warningsToBrowser fatalsToBrowser);
            use File::Basename;
            $CGI::POST_MAX;
            my $safe_filename_characters = "a-zA-Z0-9_.-";
            my $cgi = new CGI;
            print $cgi->header ( );
            my $file = $cgi->param('xml');
            my $lines;
            open(DATA,"<$file") or die "Can't open data $!";
            $lines = <DATA>;
            close(DATA);
            print $lines;    
            print abs_path($file);
            open(OUT, '>dirname($file)."\\out_".basename($file)');
            print OUT $lines;
            close(OUT);   
        print <<END_HERE;

<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Thanks!</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    img {border: none;}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>Thanks for uploading your file!</p>
    </body>
</html>
END_HERE

print "Welcome Come Again";
```

i want to execute the xml file in any folder or drive without the cgi-bin folder please any one help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Dave Cross was kind enough to give you a lot of pointers in your earlier question regarding this script: [How to upload and open a file in xampp apache server using CGI Perl Script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25362427/how-to-upload-and-open-a-file-in-xampp-apache-server-using-cgi-perl-script)  It would be wise to address all the things he pointed out before asking a subsequent question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try again.

This program runs on your web server. The path that you get from `$cgi->param('xml')` is the path on the client. It is extremely unlikely that the client path will exist on server - as your error message shows.

If you want to get the location of the uploaded file, you can use `$cgi->tmpFileName($filename)`.

If you want a filehandle that is already open on the uploaded file, you can use `$cgi->upload('xml')`.

If you want the name of the file that was uploaded then you can use `$cgi->param('xml')` - but you'll need to remove the directory path from the start of that value as it is useless to you on the server.

I explained all of this in answer to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25362427/how-to-upload-and-open-a-file-in-xampp-apache-server-using-cgi-perl-script). But for some reason you seem to have ignored my previous answer. I'd be interested to hear why.

Comment: Its working nice @Dave. I want the directory path of xml file. Because i want to write the output xml to the same location where am getting that xml file.I use this  open $local_out_fh, '>', "$local_fn" or die $!; but the file is writing in cgi-bin folder only.

Comment: If you have an additional question, then it's probably best to start a new discussion.